# Run NUnit tests in Appcenter?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit, nunit-3.0, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Xamarin project that I regularly push to Appcenter, where it's build. That works fine, but now I added NUnit 3 tests to my solution and while they execute fine locally, they seem not to be executed during Appcenter build.

How do I configure my solution so that my test project is executed on Appcenter? Seems like one has to [combine it with Xamarin.UITest](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/faster-android-tests-and-nunit-3/), but I don't really understand what steps are necessary for that. Note that my NUnit tests are not UI tests, they are normal unit tests.

Update:
Quote from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/faster-android-tests-and-nunit-3/

> Now you can update your NUnit package along with UITest to the latest versions and run tests both locally and in App Center,

So I would expect NUnit tests to be run during App Center build without an additional script. Ca anyone shed some light on this? Adding a bounty now.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found to have AppCenter run a project's NUnit tests was by adding a post-build script for each app and install `NunitXml.TestLogger` Nuget package into your NUnit project, which will output an Xml file of your test results.

To create a post-build script it needs to be in the root directory of the Android/iOS .csproj and named `appcenter-post-build.sh`. Then your script should look something like this:

```
#Android post build script
#Make sure the directly to the NUnit csproj is correct
ProjectPath="$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY\YourProject.NUnit\YourProject.NUnit.csproj"
echo "$ProjectPath"
#To generate the xml file it requires nuget NunitXml.TestLogger
dotnet test "$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY" --logger:"nunit;LogFilePath=TestResults.xml"
echo "NUnit tests result:"
pathOfTestResults=$(find $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY -name 'TestResults.xml')
cat $pathOfTestResults
echo

#Looks for a failing test and causes the build to fail if found
grep -q 'result="Failed"' $pathOfTestResults

if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
then 
echo "A test Failed" 
exit 1
else 
echo "All tests passed" 
fi
```

The last part should cause your AppCenter build to fail if a test does. Also, you may need to try building it twice in AppCenter before it picks up that a post build script has been added to your repo.

Comment: thanks, that looks like a good way, yet I interpret this blog post https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/faster-android-tests-and-nunit-3/ "Now you can update your NUnit package along with UITest to the latest versions and run tests both locally and in App Center," as there is a more official way, maybe without scripting. That's why I yet didn't select this as answer.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think to use the official version you have to pay for the Test tier in AppCenter. Otherwise, you'll have to set up a build script to run your Unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the blog is that the UITest used to based on nunit 2.x. So, previously if you accidentally updated to nunit3.x your UITests wouldn't work.

They have now updated it so that you can use nunit 3.x to run your UI tests.

I believe @Nick Peppers give the correct approach. Sample post build script here:
https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/xamarin/nunit-test/appcenter-post-build.sh